# C# CSOM can't find created list field on list

Tags: development, csom

I'm creating list and adding fields to it from code (since I need to do it dynamically), but there is a problem with one field, that I create last (Multi line/Note) and when I try to add data to it, I get an error: Field WorkflowData does not exist. Possible, that other user has deleted it

**Code part**

Field name: `private static string _workflowInfo = "WorkflowData";`

Creating field:

```
Field fApproval = newList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(string.Format("<Field DisplayName='{0}' Type='{1}' />", _workflowInfo, FieldType.Note),
                                           true,
                                           AddFieldOptions.DefaultValue);
fApproval.Update();
newList.Update();
cDestination.ExecuteQuery();
```

Adding Data to field:

```
newItem[_workflowInfo] = workflowInfo.ToString(); // Or any data, tried to add just string as well, didn't work

newItem.Update();
cDestination.ExecuteQuery();
```

Although that field exsists on my Item and `cDestination.ExecuteQuery()` works passes without errors:

[image]

**Edit**

The field exists on the list

[image]

[image]

**Found the problem**

Problem was, that when I was uploading my file to SharePoint, I technically just took old File and added it to new eviorment. So all metadata from that file came through and including `Context.Url`, which means, when I tried to add my `WorkflowData` info to it, it didn't find that field, since it didn't exist on old list.

Here is a pice of code, that works:

```
// Get file collection to add new documents to
FileCollection destFiles = cDestination.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(newList.ParentWebUrl.TrimEnd('/') + "/" + newList.Title.Replace(" ", "")).Files;
cDestination.Load(destFiles);
cDestination.ExecuteQuery();

var fileInform = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(cOriginal, file.ServerRelativeUrl); // Get file content from SharePoint

var fi = new FileCreationInformation
{
      Url = newList.ParentWebUrl.TrimEnd('/') + "/" + newList.Title.Replace(" ", "") + "/" + file.Name, //cOriginal.Web.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/') + "/" + newList.Title.Replace(" ", "") + "/" + file.Name,
      Content = ReadFully(fileInform.Stream), //System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(File.OpenBinaryDirect(cOriginal, file.ServerRelativeUrl)), //System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(cOriginal + "/" + file.ServerRelativeUrl),
      Overwrite = true
};

var fileUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", newList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, file.Name);

newItem = destFiles.Add(fi).ListItemAllFields; // Get back new file that has been created
cDestination.ExecuteQuery();
```